# Convert string value to uint (hex)

Tags: c#, string, hex

I have string like 10000005 (and it is hex) and i want to make uint hex value like:
0x10000005

How can i do this?

Example:

```
string hexStr="10000005"
uint hex= //???  (0x10000005);
```

P.S. I need that hex should be : 0x10000005

Answer (score 1):

You can use the the standard `Convert` class which exposes `ToUInt32` method for this.

```
string hexString = "10000005";
uint hex = Convert.ToUInt32(hexString, 16);
hex.ToString("X") // Output: 10000005
```

Comment: but hex will not be 0x10000005 at this code

Comment: @AdmiralLand yes, because you've converted it to an int. I've updated answer to show you how to get desired result.